# c++ locale without RTTI

Tags: c++, rtti

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class commaNumpunct: public std::numpunct<char> {
    protected:
        char_type do_decimal_point() const { return ','; }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::locale locale;
    std::locale locale2(locale, new commaNumpunct());
    std::cout.imbue(locale2);

    std::cout << 1.43 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If I compile it normally:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

I get:

```
1,43
```

as expected. If I compile it:

```
g++ -fno-rtti main.cpp
```

I get:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__cxxabiv1::__dynamic_cast (src_ptr=src_ptr@entry=0x614c20, src_type=0x7ffff7dcb740 <typeinfo for std::locale::facet>, 
    dst_type=dst_type@entry=0x7ffff7dcd068 <typeinfo for std::locale::facet::__shim>, src2dst=src2dst@entry=-2) at /build/gcc-multilib/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/dyncast.cc:72
72  /build/gcc-multilib/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/dyncast.cc: No such file or directory.
```

Is there a way to use locale in this way and simultaneously have RTTI turned off?

Comment: Disabling RTTI means you're no longer working with a standards-compliant C++ compiler. Which is fine, but you should really mention and tag your particular GCC and libstdc++ versions.

Comment: BTW, it's likely that the only practical solution involves custom edits to libstdc++.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not.

Facets are accessed using [`std::use_facet`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/use_facet). The fact that it might throw a [`bad_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/bad_cast) is a pretty strong indication that is contains a `dynamic_cast`. So would need RTTI.